# How does Ant Design Pro implement multiple levels of nested tables and implement editable tables？

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd, web-frontend, ant-design-pro

I have a project where I need to design a **three-level nested table** with the **editable table** as the innermost layer.

The format is as follows：

```
|      | A    | B     | C     | D        |
| ---- | ---- | ----- | ----- | -------- |
|   -  | A1   | B1    | C1    | D1       |
|      |      | **a** | **b** | c        |
|      |   -  | a1    | b1    | c1       |
|      |      | **M** | **N** | **O**    |
|      |      | m1    | n1    | editBtn  |
|      |      | m1    | n1    | editBtn  |
|      |   +  | a2    | b2    | c2       |
|   +  | A2   | B2    | C2    | D2       |
|   +  | A3   | B3    | C3    | D3       |
```

`ProComponent` provides [secondary nested table](https://procomponents.ant.design/en-US/components/table#nested-tables) and [editable tables](https://procomponents.ant.design/en-US/components/editable-table#editable-forms).

But the table nesting is `expandedRowRender`, the second level is still a table, can not **replace the editable table**, and I want the third level nested editable table. I've tried a few things, but none of them have the same effect.

```
const waitTime = (time: number = 100) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(true);
    }, time);
  });
};

type DataSourceType = {
  id: React.Key;
  title?: string;
  decs?: string;
  state?: string;
  created_at?: string;
  update_at?: string;
  children?: DataSourceType[];
};

const defaultData: DataSourceType[] = [
  {
    id: 624748504,
    title: '活动名称一',
    decs: '这个活动真好玩',
    state: 'open',
    created_at: '2020-05-26T09:42:56Z',
    update_at: '2020-05-26T09:42:56Z',
  },
  {
    id: 624691229,
    title: '活动名称二',
    decs: '这个活动真好玩',
    state: 'closed',
    created_at: '2020-05-26T08:19:22Z',
    update_at: '2020-05-26T08:19:22Z',
  },
];

const expandedRowRender2 = () => {
  const [editableKeys, setEditableRowKeys] = useState<React.Key[]>([]);
  const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState<DataSourceType[]>([]);

  const columns: ProColumns<DataSourceType>[] = [
    {
      title: '活动名称',
      dataIndex: 'title',
      formItemProps: (form, { rowIndex }) => {
        return {
          rules: rowIndex > 2 ? [{ required: true, message: '此项为必填项' }] : [],
        };
      },
      // 第二行不允许编辑
      editable: (text, record, index) => {
        return index !== 0;
      },
      width: '30%',
    },
    {
      title: '状态',
      key: 'state',
      dataIndex: 'state',
      valueType: 'select',
      valueEnum: {
        all: { text: '全部', status: 'Default' },
        open: {
          text: '未解决',
          status: 'Error',
        },
        closed: {
          text: '已解决',
          status: 'Success',
        },
      },
    },
    {
      title: '描述',
      dataIndex: 'decs',
      fieldProps: (from, { rowKey, rowIndex }) => {
        if (from.getFieldValue([rowKey || '', 'title']) === '不好玩') {
          return {
            disabled: true,
          };
        }
        if (rowIndex > 9) {
          return {
            disabled: true,
          };
        }
        return {};
      },
    },
    {
      title: '活动时间',
      dataIndex: 'created_at',
      valueType: 'date',
    },
    {
      title: '操作',
      valueType: 'option',
      width: 200,
      render: (text, record, _, action) => [
        <a
          key="editable"
          onClick={() => {
            action?.startEditable?.(record.id);
          }}
        >
          编辑
        </a>,
      ],
    },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <EditableProTable<DataSourceType>
        rowKey="id"
        // headerTitle="可编辑表格"
        // maxLength={5}
        // 关闭默认的新建按钮
        recordCreatorProps={false}
        columns={columns}
        request={async () => ({
          data: defaultData,
          total: 3,
          success: true,
        })}
        value={dataSource}
        onChange={setDataSource}
        editable={{
          type: 'multiple',
          editableKeys,
          onSave: async (rowKey, data, row) => {
            console.log(rowKey, data, row);
            await waitTime(2000);
          },
          onChange: setEditableRowKeys,
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export type Status = {
  color: string;
  text: string;
};

export type TableListItem = {
  key: number;
  name: string;
  containers: number;
  creator: string;
  createdAt: number;
};
const tableListDataSource: TableListItem[] = [];

const creators = ['付小小', '曲丽丽', '林东东', '陈帅帅', '兼某某'];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
  tableListDataSource.push({
    key: i,
    name: 'AppName',
    containers: Math.floor(Math.random() * 20),
    creator: creators[Math.floor(Math.random() * creators.length)],
    createdAt: Date.now() - Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000),
  });
}

const columns: ProColumns<TableListItem>[] = [
  {
    title: '产品名称',
    width: 120,
    dataIndex: 'name',
    render: (_) => <a>{_}</a>,
  },
  {
    title: '容器数量',
    width: 120,
    dataIndex: 'containers',
    align: 'right',
    sorter: (a, b) => a.containers - b.containers,
  },

  {
    title: '创建者',
    width: 120,
    dataIndex: 'creator',
    valueEnum: {
      all: { text: '全部' },
      付小小: { text: '付小小' },
      曲丽丽: { text: '曲丽丽' },
      林东东: { text: '林东东' },
      陈帅帅: { text: '陈帅帅' },
      兼某某: { text: '兼某某' },
    },
  },
  {
    title: (
      <>
        创建时间
        <Tooltip placement="top" title="这是一段描述">
          <QuestionCircleOutlined style={{ marginLeft: 4 }} />
        </Tooltip>
      </>
    ),
    width: 140,
    key: 'since',
    dataIndex: 'createdAt',
    valueType: 'date',
    sorter: (a, b) => a.createdAt - b.createdAt,
  },
  {
    title: '操作',
    width: 164,
    key: 'option',
    valueType: 'option',
    render: () => [
      <a key="1">链路</a>,
      <a key="2">报警</a>,
      <a key="3">监控</a>,
      <a key="4">
        <EllipsisOutlined />
      </a>,
    ],
  },
];

const expandedRowRender = () => {
  const data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    data.push({
      key: i,
      date: '2014-12-24 23:12:00',
      name: 'This is production name',
      upgradeNum: 'Upgraded: 56',
    });
  }

  return (
    <ProTable
      columns={[
        { title: 'Date', dataIndex: 'date', key: 'date' },
        { title: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', key: 'name' },

        { title: 'Upgrade Status', dataIndex: 'upgradeNum', key: 'upgradeNum' },
        {
          title: 'Action',
          dataIndex: 'operation',
          key: 'operation',
          valueType: 'option',
          render: () => [<a key="Pause">Pause</a>, <a key="Stop">Stop</a>],
        },
      ]}
      headerTitle={false}
      expandable={{ expandedRowRender: expandedRowRender3 }}
      search={false}
      options={false}
      dataSource={data}
      pagination={false}
    />
  );
};



export default () => {
  return (
    <ProTable<TableListItem>
      columns={columns}
      request={(params, sorter, filter) => {
        // 表单搜索项会从 params 传入，传递给后端接口。
        console.log(params, sorter, filter);
        return Promise.resolve({
          data: tableListDataSource,
          success: true,
        });
      }}
      rowKey="key"
      pagination={{
        showQuickJumper: true,
      }}
      expandable={{ expandedRowRender }}
      search={false}
      dateFormatter="string"
      headerTitle="嵌套表格"
      options={false}
    />
  );
};
```

The following error occurred while the browser was displaying a level 3 editable table

```
Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
▼ 5 stack frames were expanded.
updateWorkInProgressHook
http://localhost:8000/mf-dep_vendors-node_modules_react-dom_index_js.7bb20710.async.js:15171:15
updateReducer
http://localhost:8000/mf-dep_vendors-node_modules_react-dom_index_js.7bb20710.async.js:15229:14
updateState
http://localhost:8000/mf-dep_vendors-node_modules_react-dom_index_js.7bb20710.async.js:15650:10
useState
http://localhost:8000/mf-dep_vendors-node_modules_react-dom_index_js.7bb20710.async.js:16451:16
useState
http://localhost:8000/mf-dep_vendors-node_modules_react_index_js.598bdd42.async.js:1618:21

  49 | const expandedRowRender3 = () => {
> 50 |   const [editableKeys, setEditableRowKeys] = useState<React.Key[]>([]);
  51 |   const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState<DataSourceType[]>([]);
  52 |   const columns: ProColumns<DataSourceType>[] = [
  53 |     {
```

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it.